# Spray IO with Slick Use Conf File

Tags: scala, slick, spray

I'm using Spray with Slick. Spray is actually very easy to use, and the same goes with Slick. However, the infamous Slick way to connect to Database is like:

```
  Database.forURL("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/SprayBlog?characterEncoding=UTF-8", user="xxxx", password="xxx", driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver") withSession {
    implicit session =>

      (Article.articles.ddl ++ User.users.ddl).create
  }
```

I hate typing this much whenever I do a database connection. I have used Play-Slick framework before, and Play has this `application.conf`, with which I can store my database connection address, username and password. I don't know if this is true, but shouldn't people store their database info on an encrypted file, and I may be wrong but I feel `conf` is blocked from outside access and encrypted.

So is there a way for me to call database manipulations easier?? If I do want to put the info in the `conf`, how can I access it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store your db in a val or write a def that abstracts over what you feel is repetitive. withSession is good for connection scoping. I don't know spray conf files, but they may use Typesafe config, which is a library that allows to read the file. Spray probably also exposes its config through an api.

Comment: if you need access to the db from many controller files, you would make the db a singleton somehow right?

Comment: You can place the val in a singleton object and import from there. If you want to be able to swap out the db instance you can either inherit from a trait with an abstract db member or put some swapping logic that depends on config in your singleton.

Answer (score 2):

With Slick 2.1.0 you can use `Database.forConfig()`.

In application.conf:

```
db {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/DatabaseName"
    driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    user = "root"
    password = ""
}
```

In your database access code:

```
import scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
import models.Item
import tables.ItemTable

class ItemService {

  val items = TableQuery[ItemTable]

  def all: List[Item] = Database.forConfig("db") withSession { implicit session: Session =>
    items.list
  }
}
```

Comment: Haha apparently this is a new feature!